# How to Combine to Two tables with two values to Join

Tags: mysql, join

I have this two tables

```
tbl_Output

    ref_id1 | desc1 | rec_type
       1     value1      1     
       1     value2      2  



tbl_Output2

    ref_id2 | desc2 | rec_type
        1      value3     1
        1      value4     2
```

How can I join this two tables? To show

```
ref_id1 | desc1  | ref_id2 | desc2  | rec_type
   1      value1      1      value3      1
   1      value2      1      value4      2
```

Instead of

```
ref_id1 | desc1  | ref_id2 | desc2  | rec_type
   1      value1      1      value3      1
   1      value2      1      value4      2
   1      value1      1      value3      1
   1      value2      1      value4      2

Here is my Query:
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_Output1 as O
  inner JOIN tbl_Output2 as O2 on
  O.ref_id1 = O2.ref_id2
```

Note: I already used different kinds of join.

Comment: Can you reformat your top part?

Comment: Does the `rec_type` have to match?

Comment: Yes it should. I was able to join it using @tim's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining on *both* the `id1`/`id2` columns *and* the `rec_type` columns:

```
SELECT t1.ref_id1,
       t1.desc1,
       t2.ref_id2,
       t2.desc2,
       t1.rec_type
FROM tbl_Output t1
INNER JOIN tbl_Output2 t2
    ON t1.ref_id1 = t2.ref_id2 AND
       t1.rec_type = t2.rec_type
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way:

```
SELECT o1.ref_id1,o1.desc1,o2.ref_id2,o2.desc2,rec_type FROM tbl_Output1 o1
  INNER JOIN tbl_Output2 o2 USING(rec_type);
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3192/1).